# Make field required before publishing

Tags: plone

I understand how to make a field required at the time of saving content. Is there a technique for making it required before publishing?

Comment: formlib? z3c.form? std AT content type form? also, I think you really meant "just before presenting the form to user", right? pls, give more details

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you meant "making it required before saving," as elaborated at [Plone Workflow: How to check for multiple attributes of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419176/plone-workflow-how-to-check-for-multiple-attributes-of-an-object), you'd have to use a transition guard expression.

Comment: typo, I meant "making it required before publishing" not " making it required before saving". I have edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Jon's answer is correct. Workflow transition guard expressions are the easiest way to require a field for publication.

Comment: Maybe wishful thinking: might be nice at some point to generalize this at some point and find a way to spell this out (for Dexterity types, at least) on schema (directive), in supermodel XML, schema editor, and some kind of cue in the UI that the field is marked as "eventually required" or something similar (something distinct from the red dot), along with some kind of convenience / view that guard expressions can use to actually enforce this.